# Matrix of ratios of all pairs of elements from a vector

Tags: matrices

Say I have a vector ${\bf x} = [x_1 \:\: x_2 \:\: x_3 \dots x_n]$. Consider the matrix ${\bf X}$ where $ij$-th element is the ratio $$\frac{x_i}{x_j}$$ Does this matrix have a special name?

Pardon if this is common knowledge, but a quick google search did not reveal anything.

EDIT: Alternatively if I have two vectors $\bf x$ and $\bf y$ and the $ij$-th element is $$\frac{x_i}{y_j}$$ what then?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this matrix has a special name, but it does have a special form. If you let $y = 1/x$ be the vector of all multiplicative inverses of entries of $x$, then your matrix is the outer-product $xy^T$. In particular, this says your matrix has rank 1. It may also simplify computations involving the matrix.